# Where to find GIT Repository Editor into jBPM/KIE Workbench

Tags: git, jboss, wildfly, jbpm, kie-workbench

I follow official [jBPM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/).

Downloaded `jBPM-7.5.0.Final-installer-full.zip` and run the following commands:

```
$ ant install.demo
$ ant start.demo
```

[Chapter 10.3.3](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_wb.vfsrepository) says that there should be `Repository Editor`

However I see nothing. There no such items neither in `Administration` nor in `Projects` views. It looks like obsolete documentation.

Can anybody help me to find the `Repository Editor`?

Comment: me too not able to locate 'Repository Editor'. For each asset, in 'Overview' tab I can see option to select older version of file. Looks like doc is referring to this feature.

Comment: @AbhijitHumbe, it's better, but do you know how to change GIT branches now?

Comment: @Abhijit perhaps if you vote up the question, it will attract more attention.

Answer (score 0):

There are few variations in kie workbench. This version(kie drools wb) does not have some features. Download this war file:
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/kie/kie-wb/7.0.0.Final/kie-wb-7.0.0.Final-wildfly10.war
And deploy this on wildfly 10.0.0. It has GIT Repository editor, along with some other features.

Comment: I actually found that doc a bit misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but your link gives me 404.
I've checked my `war` file, it's https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/kie/kie-wb/7.5.0.Final/kie-wb-7.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war